# unknown column in field list error with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I did

```
include_once'include/connection.php';
$fname = 'olo';
$lname = 'mike';
$uname = 'nolo';
$pass = 'mmmmm';



$query2 = "INSERT INTO imt.`$uname`
(fname, lname, pass) VALUES (`$fname`, `$lname`, `$pass`)";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection);
if(!$result2){echo mysql_error();}

var_dump($query2);
```

but got this output

```
Unknown column 'olo' in 'field list'
string 'INSERT INTO imt.`nolo`
(fname, lname, pass) VALUES (`olo`, `mike`, `mmmmm`)' (length=76)
```

I also tried using single quotes and/ or curly braces but still the same thing. I switched the variables to the actual data and got the same error. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `backticks`, but also quotes

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO imt.`$uname` (fname, lname, pass) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$pass')";
                                                                ^ here ^  ^      ^
```

`backticks` are needed when you have to deal with column names which matches native SQL functions, otherwise they are not necessary. In this case if you'd like to use them you should do like this

```
"INSERT INTO imt.$uname (`fname`, `lname`, `pass`) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$pass')"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
VALUES (`$fname`, `$lname`, `$pass`)
```

should be

```
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$pass')
```

Comment: ...I DID try that some minutes ago and it didn't work. Just did it now just to check again and it worked....don't understand

Comment: It should be something else the query as shown above should work. Check here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67620

Comment: @brown.cn: You might have tried with back ticks and hence did not work. And with single quotes it should have worked.