# Unknown column in field list using Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server

when i testing the sql code i got the error of #1054 - Unknown column '321sa' in 'field list'how to retify that what i trid so far i attached below

```
INSERT INTO member (mno,pname,dob,eperson,relationship,ephone)
    VALUES         (2323,321sa,dasda,sadas,asdas,33333)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column '321sa' in 'field list'
```

Comment: need to quote (with `'....'`or `"...."`) your string values.

Comment: DOB should be a DATE and not a varchar()

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO member (mno,nic,pname,dob,eperson,relationship,ephone)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$mno,$nic,$pname,$dob,$eperson,$relationship,$ephone);

Comment: this code y data is not added without error

Comment: Did you-`->execute()` the prepared statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what operation are you trying to perform?
also heres a hack Enclose any string to be passed to the mysql server inside single quotes; e.g.:

```
$name = "my name"
$query = " INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 1 , '$name') "
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '321sa' in 'field list'             what was a probelem

Comment: ok saw a similar question try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066782/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-with-mysql